# Stop MediaPlayer In Bacgkround Based on Timer

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer

My goal is to stop a MediaPlayer object based on a timer in an Android application. I would like the sounds to stop even if it the app is in the background. What is the best approach to accomplish this? Should use an `AlarmManager`?

On related question, as I understood it, in order for my `MediaPlayer` to play int he background, it needs to be  implemented with a `Service`. It turns out I did not implement the `MediaPlayer` with a `Service` yet it still plays in the background as I would hope. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is indeed a perfect use case for an alarm.

Yes, the MediaPlayer may keep playing media if you don't explicitly stop it in `onPause()`. You should release the MediaPlayer, because it can really be a bad experience for the user, in particular if your activity is killed because the system needs memory, or if another application tries to start the MediaPlayer. Right now, what happens on configChange (eg: if the user rotates the screen)? Please implement a service as documented.

Comment: I will take your advice and impleent a service and an AlarmManager. Nothing happens upon screen rotation. When are you suggesting that I release the MediaPlayer? Thanks.